# How to allow only one container to expand on more click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement paper cards functionality.

Everything seems to work fine, but I cannot restrict only one container to expand on more click. I can open multiple containers at once, and that is not what I want. I want active container to close automatically as I try to open another one. Here is my code:
HMTL:

```js
(function ($) {
 $(window).load(function(){
  if ($(".navBoxes").length > 0)
  {
   var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html").item(0);
   var hasCSS3 = (html.className.indexOf("no-csstransforms") == -1)
   
   $(".no-csstransforms .larger").toggleClass("undisplayed");
   $(".larger").children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
   
   // Expand nav box
   $(".nav.plus").click(function(){
            $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
            var smallerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
    var largerBox = smallerBox.next();
    
    if (hasCSS3)
    {
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
     largerBox.toggleClass("atop").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
    }
    else
    {
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
     largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
    }
    
    largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
        largerBox.addClass("openedBox");
        return false;
   });
   
   // Contract nav box
   $(".nav.minus").click(function(){
        var largerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
        $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
    var smallerBox = largerBox.prev();
    
    largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
    
    if (hasCSS3)
    {
     largerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
     largerBox.toggleClass("atop")
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded");
     //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
    }
    else
    {
     largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
     //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
    }
    
    return false;
   }); 
  }
  setOrgChartDimensions();
 });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.navBoxes{
 width: 522px;}
.navBoxes .undisplayed
{display: none;}
.navBoxes .navBox
{position: absolute;
 float: left;
 clear: none;
 padding: 0 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 box-sizing: border-box;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller{
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
 z-index: 2;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller.atop{z-index: 4;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger
{height: auto;
    opacity: 0.95;
    overflow: auto;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
.navBoxes .navBox.hidden
{opacity: 0.0;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger.atop
{z-index: 3;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .icon{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;}
.navBoxes .navBox .title
{font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 20px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller .title
{margin-top: 8px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller a
{color: #fff;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .title
{position: relative;
 top: 10px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body
{margin-top: 20px;}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body a
{ color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav
{ position: absolute;
 width: 35px;
 height: 30px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav a
{ color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.plus
{ top: 110px;
 left: 110px;}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.minus
{ position:relative;
 float:right; }
.navBoxes .box1
{ background-color: #185394;
 transform-origin: top left;}
.navBoxes .box1.smaller:hover
{ background-color: #214872;}
.navBoxes .box2
{ background-color: #c94747;
 transform-origin: top right;}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller:hover{background-color: #b24444;}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller{margin-left: 180px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="navBoxes">
 <div class="navBox box1 smaller">
  <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 1</div>
  <div class="nav plus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box1 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
  <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box2 smaller">
  <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 2</a></div>
  <div class="nav plus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navBox box2 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
   <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set a class that represents the "expanded" div. lets say you set "openedBox" class whenever you expand. now you can use jQuery before setting this class to search for all the element with that class `$("openedBox").removeClass("openedBox").hide();` and they will not show and then you add yhe class to the current box

Comment: By the way you shouldn't use so many classes for the same properties. you should have box_bigger, box_smaller and not box1_bigger, box2_bigger, box1_smaller box2_smaller it's not the correct way

Comment: Saar thank you for your reply. How would you recommend to set openedBox class. Can you please provide an example. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, Your problem is that you have both "hidden" and "undisplayed" classes and you are using them in a mixed way. I only handled the "undisplayed". my solution is valid for your issue, the only thing you should check is the toggleClass that prevents it from appearing after 1 time

Answer (score 0):

What I do in the code here is whenever you want to open a box
I remove the class `openedBox` from whoever has it (might be null).
And I put that class after it only on the box I want to be open.
When I close the box I remove it as well.
Find these lines:

```
    $(".nav.plus").click(function(){
        var smallerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
```

Replace it with:

```
        $(".nav.plus").click(function(){
            $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
            var smallerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
```

Find these lines:

```
        largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
        return false;
```

Replace it with:

```
        largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
        largerBox.addClass("openedBox");
        return false;
```

find:

```
    $(".nav.minus").click(function(){
        var largerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
```

replace it with:

```
    $(".nav.minus").click(function(){
        var largerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
        $(".openedBox").addClass("undisplayed").removeClass("openedBox");
```

Comment: Saar, thank you for the example. It seems like I have a problem with the code. When I try to expand second box while the first one is opened, it replaces expanded container. But I'm not able to reopen the first one. Does it mean that I can only open container once? Please advice and thank you for your effort to help me

Comment: Hi Irina, See my code addition now. I changed it a bit

Comment: I just updated my snippet with the code you provided, it still restricting me from opening the same container more than one time

Comment: Hi, if you add a working jsFiddle I will be able to help you